# Determining location of egress traffic in GCP Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function deployed in GCP. One thing the function does is make an http call to a 3rd party. The function is deployed to us-central1. I do not have a VPC setup, and haven't made any modifications to the network options in GCP.

About 1% of my calls to the 3rd party are receiving 403 responses - the 3rd party says those calls are originating in Australia, which is why the calls result in a 403.

Shouldn't my traffic originate in the US? If not, I don't necessarily need a static IP address for my function, but is there a way to limit my function's egress traffic to a specific region? How can I determine where the egress traffic is actually originating from?

Comment: Which region is the third party located in? You say you do not have a VPC, but you have one configured by default when you create a GCP account. There are two network tiers, Standard and Premium. Egress traffic exits Google Cloud in the same region as the service for Standard. For Premium, egress traffic exits Google Cloud closest to the destination. Do you know what the IP address is for the Australian connect attempts? If yes, you can look up who owns that IP address. All egress connections from Google will come from an IP address owned by Google. Edit your post with details.

Answer (score 1):

As per @JohnHanley:

> VPC is configured by default when you create a GCP account. There are two network tiers based on this documentation on [Network Service Tiers overview](https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers/docs/overview); **Premium** and **Standard**.
> Below are the differences of **Premium** and **Standard**:

| Premium Tier | Standard Tier |
| --- | --- |
| Highest performance: Traffic between the internet and VM instances in your VPC network is routed by keeping it within Google's network as much as possible. | Cost optimized: Traffic between the internet and VM instances in your VPC network is routed over the internet in general. |
| For services that need global availability. | For services hosted entirely within a region. |
| Unique to Google Cloud. | Performance is comparable to other cloud providers. |
| Premium Tier is the default unless you [make configuration changes](https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers/docs/overview#configuring_standard_tier_for_load_balancing). |  |

You can also check this documentation on [setting the network tier](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/implementing-iam-access-control-code-hashicorp-terraform).